# Media query CSS overriding CSS without satisfying the width condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I have this css:

.realiser-devis {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 23px;
font-weight: 700;
margin: 0;
color: #fff;
}

and i want to reduce the font size if the screen width is less than 1600 px

```
@media only screen and  (max-width:1600px) {
        .realiser-devis {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        
    }​
```

the problem is that the css inside the media query is working without satisfying the condition;
the width of my screen is 1800px and the font size is 12 px

is there somthing i'm missing ?

Regards

Amir

Answer (score 3):

You may be missing the responsive meta tag in the `<head>` section.

Make sure you have this in the `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Read more about that [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/).

Comment: i have it on the html, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please check width of screen using this command in your console while inspecting

```
console.log(window.screen.width)
```

if it's still 1800 please reduce your media query `max-width` to 500 and check, if it works then you should check what issue with screen width you have.

Otherwise please try using media queries without key word `only`(it can affect older browsers):

```
@media screen and  (max-width:1600px) {
    .realiser-devis {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

useful information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: This appear to be the same as Rob's answer from about a week ago. You added a better link, but didn't include any explanation in the question. Please read [answer].